# Android question: When using SimpleCursorAdapter, how can I format one of the columns

Tags: android, database, datetime, listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to create a list that is mapped to a database query, however, one of the fields in the database is a timestamp which when displayed should be displayed as a date like "Wednesday, March 2" instead of the actual value in the database which is something like 1299517239487...

I can solve this by rephrasing the query or by decorating the cursor after I do the query, but I would much rather have the simple cursor adapter display this column in that specific way.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do it?

some code:

```
// the desired columns to be bound
String[] columns = new String[] { DBHelper.COL_START_TIME, DBHelper.COL_AMOUNT};
// the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.dayMonthDate, R.id.amount};

// create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data as well as the layout information
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.single_activity,cursor, columns, to);
```

I would like to be able to add some kind of post processor to the adapter in order to fix that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [setViewBinder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setViewBinder%28android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder%29) method of [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) to have a [ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html) manually set the values for the views but that will get called for every column.

Comment: doesn't that override the mapping that's defined in the adapter though?

Comment: API says that if you return false from the bind method, then the adapter will try to figure it out. I'm assuming it will override what you choose, but if you return false, it will use the default mapping.